# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'OESAC.Data.MyDbContext' while attempting to activate 'OESAC.Pages.Courses.IndexModel'

Tags: sqlite, dbcontext, razor-pages

I have searched StackOverflow and the world for solutions. Pretty sure if it was a snake it would have bit me.
Razor Pages Web Application, VS 2017, runs and shows Home page. I want to show a Pages/Courses/Index.chstml page connected to Courses table. When I click on the Courses link, that is when everything blows up.

Here is my "MyDbContext" class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace OESAC.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sponsors> Sponsors{ get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data source=oesac_new.db");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Index file that is triggering the error. It is in Pages.Courses folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OESAC.Data;

namespace OESAC.Pages.Courses
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly OESAC.Data.MyDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(OESAC.Data.MyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public List<OESAC.Data.Courses> Courses { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Courses = await _context.Courses.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'OESAC.Data.MyDbContext' while attempting to activate 'OESAC.Pages.Courses.IndexModel'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(PageContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateModelFactory>b__0(PageContext pageContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I started piecing apart the error and I received some help.

I found this mentioned and I added it to my Startup.cs ConfigureServices

*Everything in .NET Core is built around dependency injection instead of using static instances of things like ConfigurationManager.
You could do this in a couple different ways.
First would be registering your DbContext in Startup.cs ConfigureServices using something like this:*

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Here is the question and answer location for the above:
[How to pass connection string from appsettings.[name].json to DbContext in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176564/how-to-pass-connection-string-from-appsettings-name-json-to-dbcontext-in-net)

===================================================

The second item I had to add was this I found in another thread (I changed the context name to reflect my MyDbContext):

*As the error said it if you configure your MyDbContext through AddDbContext then you need too add a constructor that receive a parameter of type DbContextOptions into your MyDbContext class like below*

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{ }
```

*If you don't do that, ASP.Net Core will not be able to inject the configuration you set with AddDbContext.* (remember the answer in the first URL I found said "Everything in .NET Core is built around dependency injection instead of using static instances"). Note to self: learn what Dependency Injection is LOL

Go figure. You would think that Scaffolding would have done all this. What a head scratcher.

I found that here, again, on StackOverflow:

[AddDbContext was called with configuration, but the context type 'MyContext' only declares a parameterless constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947795/adddbcontext-was-called-with-configuration-but-the-context-type-mycontext-onl)